# How to send ENTER from keyboard using TestStack.White Framework

Tags: ui-automation, white-framework

I am writing a c# code to test UI in my application. I want to send ENTER from Keyboard.
I already checked `TestStack.White.WindowsAPI.KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys`. It doesnt contain any method send ENTER.

Thanks.

Comment: `KeyboardUI` has `Enter` which is `Input` and `PressSpecialKey` `RETURN` which is `ENTER`. Somewhat misleading.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Any reason you can't use `KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.RETURN` ? It should do the same thing and get you what you need.